# How stackObjects function sort detected objects

Tags: r, image-processing

I'm using R statistic software with EBImage package for microscope image processing analysis.
I have a processed image where I can draw cell identification number above. This number comes from the row number of computefeatures dataframe.
After applying the stackobjects function, I can not find each stacked cells in the original image. I would like to know the criteria of stackobjects function to sort each image into the stack.
I've performed a simple image processing test, but I cannot understand this criteria.

```
library('EBImage')
x = readImage('test.jpg')
display(x)
```

[image: origina image]

```
x <- x < .5
display(x)
```

[image: threshold]

```
y = bwlabel(x)
display(colorLabels(y), title='Objects')
```

[image: segmented]

```
z = stackObjects(y, x)
display(z, title='Stacked objects', method = 'raster', all = TRUE)
```

[image: stacked]

As you can see. Numbers are not sorted or inverted sorted.

Regards

Comment: If detected object were from right/top to left/down, I would expect something like: "3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7, 12, 11, 10". But "8" is stacked before 9. And "11" position is understandable, why is placed as last stacked image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tests, stackObjects function sort segmented objects by y-coordinate.
Here you can see some examples to understant the behaviour of the function.

Regards
[image]

Comment: Definetly, the problem was in my real case where I used watershed method to perform the segmentation step. Watershed function seams to assign the identification value by some other method that I can not predict

Comment: Consider the answer to "how to plot features in an image." (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56043654/3508856) The `computeFeatures.moment` gives you the location of each object in the original image that you can apply to the stack of objects.